# .desktop files do not recognize $PATH variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables, shortcut-file

I have lots of programs installed, for each one I append its directory to the $PATH variable.

this is easy, I open a terminal type the name and it runs, until I decided to make a desktop file for each program. It seems desktop files do not recognize the $PATH variable

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/applications/ISE.png
Type=Application
Categories=Digital
Exec=ise
Name=Xilinx ISE
```

It does not even appear in unity menu, the command ise usually works fine in a terminal, I also tried to use the complete /path/to/ise, still does not appear in search.

but if I remove ise and put for example gedit instead. it appears in search, opens gedit and works fine. how do I make Desktop files recognize the $PATH variable and execute these commands ??

Comment: Have you tried to add the `Path=/path/to/app` value to the entry. I kwnow it doesn't answer the question but it might narrow the possibilities.

Comment: @loki I have tried that now, nothing too.

Comment: How did you updated the `PATH` variable?, in `.bashrc` or something like that?, your desktop manager might not be watching the updates inside bash or the shell you're using.

Comment: @loki yes through .bashrc

Comment: I made a mistake, try `Exec=/full/path/to/app` instead of `Path=...`, your `$PATH` variable is set on bash shells and not read by your desktop enviroment.

Comment: Never mind watching your question and you already did.

Comment: @loki I have already tried that as I wrote in the question.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a subshell? `Exec="sh -c 'ise'"`